# Kubernetes azureFile never showing up

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-files

[Github Issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/42628)

I'm using Azure ACS with Kubernetes orchestrator with Windows agents.

But I keep running into an issue when I try to use azureFile volume, it never seems to find my share.

The volume remains unknown, and when trying to browse to the website it gives access denied:

[image: Like you can see here]

But this is probably because the folder is empty.

I'll show you my .yaml file and storagestructure, i'm pretty sure my secret is correct, doublechecked it.

[image: StorageStructure]

pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: azurepod
  labels:
    Volumes: ok
spec:
  containers:
    - image: XXXX
      name: aspvolumes
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: C:\site
        name: asp-website-volume
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: crcatregistry
  nodeSelector:
    OS: windows
  volumes:
    - name: asp-website-volume
      azureFile:
        secretName: azure-secret
        shareName: asptestsite
        readOnly: false
```

Answer (score 0):

k8s azure file mount on windows node is not ready yet, the code has been merged into v1.9, see https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes/pull/11, and this feature relies on a new Windows version which is not published yet.